# Approval Process: Change Task Outcome Rejected to Stopped

Tags: sharepoint-designer

On the SharePoint Designer 2010 "Start Approval Process", if I change the "Rejected" Task Outcome to "Stopped", would I have to replace all "Rejected" to "Stopped"? Like in the Change the behavior of a single task and under When a Task Completes, "Else if Current Task:Outcome equals "Rejected" or do I use "Stopped"?